# Cannot change smoke color?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, color

I am making a smoke simulation and although I can change the color of the smoke in solid mode, it does not apply in rendered and stays a dark grey. Everything is lit brightly. I am using cycles in Blender 2.78.

Comment: Does it have a color in the render or not?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include screenshots of the render (solid mode? and rendered) as well as your node setup for the smoke material.

Comment: I do not have a smoke material set up. It has worked in other renders where I would change the color of the smoke in the "Flow" settings in the physics panel. It is a dark grey in the render.

Comment: The color of the smoke is a viewport change, not a change that will be calculated at the time of a render. A material setup is nessesary to create the desired smoke effect. You can either create one manually by mixing nodes, or use the Principled Volume shader included in the 2.79 daily builds. Hope that helps!